# Determine the range of a composite function

Tags: functions

[image]

That's the problem with the range of a function(composite function).

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$. Its easy to see that it equals $\infty$. Further $f(2) = 0$. Since $f(x)$ is continuous, range $= [0, \infty)$.